# Confused on checking out in Git

Tags: git, clearcase

I have a trouble understanding the checkout process of `Git`.
Via cli we do:
`git log` and the history.
1) How do we know which file/version is the one we want to check out? I only see hashes/author/comments/dates. Not a filename.
2) If I do `git checkout -commitid-` then I go to that previous version. Is this the same as doing a check-out in ClearCase?
3) To return to the latest changes I do: `git checkout master`. This returns to the latest version but does it do a checkout to the latest element?

Comment: Well, your not alone... we actually got a guy called Jeremy Skinner to come and spend some hours with us going through it. He is /was a moving force behind Posh Git. Throughtfully we recorded his explanations. We have made the freely availble via youtube or this short url http://ava.co.uk/git. They have had about 6,000 views in the last year (earned us about 15p!). feel free to view

Comment: I'm not familiar with Clearcase, but it sounds quite different to git. You don't check out individual files with Git, but rather an entire branch. I'd recommend you use Github's introduction just to get a general understanding: http://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confusing terminologies used by other version control systems.
`git checkout` is the command used to switch which branch you are working on.  `git checkout master` will switch you to working on the master branch.  `git checkout test` would cause you to work in a branch named test.
to try to answer your questions:

1. I don't understand this question, but I think it stems from the misunderstanding of the checkout command.  Every version of a file in git is a separate hash, git log will show you all the commits, so you can see each version of the file there.
2. to change your branch to a previous state you use the `git reset` command.  `git checkout -commitid-` will actually detach your HEAD pointer and leave you with no branch checked out.  This can be used to see what the state was like at the time of that commit
3. git checkout master will change your working branch to master.  To return to the latest changes there are lots of things people do, sometimes they stash their existing changes then delete the stash for example.

Comment: `Every version of a file in git is a separate hash, git log will show you all the commits, so you can see each version of the file there`. How do I know from `git log` which hash belongs to which file? There are no file names mentioned in `git log`

Comment: The hashes in `git log` identify commits, not files. Each commit is a snapshot of the entire repository.

Comment: But I did `git commit -m` after `adding` a file. I assumed tha it was the file that was commited

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to ClearCase (see [my old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645008/what-are-the-basic-clearcase-concepts-every-developer-should-know/645771#645771)), git doesn't operate on a file-by-file basis.
There is no "config spec" with "element selection rules".

[`git checkout`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) can be applied to a file, but by default, it restore the *content* of an all tree, not just of a file.
And it won't be the same than a `cleartool checkout,` because you don't have to mark (or even lock) a file for modification (like the `CHECKEDOUT` status in ClearCase): that doesn't make sense in a *distributed* environment. Every file in a git working tree can be modified at any time, added to the index and committed locally.

Comment: Note to self: this answer is written at "the Rock" (Alcatraz), San Francisco. Scary prison, but good phone service ;)

Comment: 1)`by default, it restore the content of an all tree, not just of a file`. Do you mean: `it restores the contents of a tree and not just of a file`? 2)`that doesn't make sense in a distributed environment. Every file in a git working tree can be modified at any time, added to the index and committed locally` How is this different with working with a local snapshot in Clearcase?

Comment: Also do you have some reference between the difference in concepts in Git and Clearcase?

Comment: @Jim 1/ yes. 2/ yo  cannot checkout a file if you don't have a connection to the vob server. If you modify a file in a snapshot view, it would be 'hijacked'. You would still need to check out and check in later on down the road. Not so with git. Every commit ('checking') is local.

Comment: @Jim the first link in my answer is a good illustration of the differences between ClearCase and git.

Comment: So no need to connect to the remote repository, right?In this case how can we know that the file we are working on, e.g hasn't been deleted by another user?

Comment: Also if there are no seletion rules i.e. config spec how does are the files to be viewed selected? Uniformly i.e. all of the same version? What if I want all the files to be the lasted and a single file to be one of a previous version? How is this possible without a config spec?

Comment: @Jim The git working tree is the representation of the all repo at a given point in time (a commit). If you start changing files, you will create a new commit for the all repo. See http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A6309+dvcs+workflow for some examples of a difference between CVCS and DVCS.

Answer (score 0):

In git branches are just links to commits, which are uniquely identified by hashes. If you want to checkout a specific commit, you need to know its hash, OR you there should be a "references" to the commit. Branches and tags are all "references" to commits, so you can use a branch name instead of the commit hash to checkout files in that commit.

> 3) To return to the latest changes I do: git checkout master. This
>   returns to the latest version but does it do a checkout to the latest
>   element?

Depends on what you mean by the latest version.If by latest you mean the latest commit, then latest commit may be on another branch, not an the `master` branch. `git reflog` shows you a list of recent changes in all references.

Comment: 1)`If you want to checkout a specific commit, you need to know its hash`.How am I supposed to know the hash of all my files (especially if there are many)? 2)`OR you there should be a "references" to the commit` I can't understand what you say here. 3) So then what does the `git checkout master` do?

Comment: Sorry for being vague. You should know the commit's hash. You can run `git log` to see the a list of commits with their hashes. But this is the difficult way to checkout a commit. The easier way to checkout a commit is to use a reference to commit, for example, `master` is a reference to the last commit on the master branch. So you can simply do `git checkout master` (or `git checkout master^1` to checkout the commit right before the last commit on that branch.